# How to change UILabel text step by step in swift

Tags: swift

I'm try to do a loading screen in my application and I want it to show the loading status text in the `UILabel` so I choose `viewDidAppear` override function to get this done but the result is it show only the completed text that I set. Here is my code in `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(false)
    loadingicon.alpha = 0
    statuslabel.alpha = 0
    loadingicon.alpha = 0
    statuslabel.alpha = 0

    // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
        //self.imganimation.frame.origin.y -= 150
        self.loadingicon.alpha = 1
        self.statuslabel.alpha = 1
        // self.loadingicon.frame.origin.y -= 50
        // self.statuslabel.frame.origin.y -= 50

    }, completion: nil)

    self.statuslabel.text = "Loading the data"

    sleep(5)

    if CheckInternet.Connection(){
            self.statuslabel.text = "Connection Success"
    } else {
    }
}
```

As you can see, I try to sleep the system for 5 second to allow it for show my text step by step but the "Loading the data" text is dissappeared and it only show me the "Connection Success" text when the process is done how can I deal with this problem

Comment: **Never** sleep on the main queue.

Comment: Why attempt any delay? Why make the user needlessly wait to use your application?

Comment: actually the loading the data is my welcome message in my application, delay it because I need them to read this message But now I know the sleep is just only slow down my process

Comment: And I'm new to swift, I didn't know that I shouldn't put sleep in main queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a delay from the current time using GCD.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
// Add the code you want to execute after the delay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(false)
    loadingicon.alpha = 0
    statuslabel.alpha = 0
    loadingicon.alpha = 0
    statuslabel.alpha = 0

    // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
        //self.imganimation.frame.origin.y -= 150
        self.loadingicon.alpha = 1
        self.statuslabel.alpha = 1
        // self.loadingicon.frame.origin.y -= 50
        // self.statuslabel.frame.origin.y -= 50

    }, completion: nil)

    self.statuslabel.text = "Loading the data"

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
      if CheckInternet.Connection(){
              self.statuslabel.text = "Connection Success"
      } else {
      }
  }
}
```